# How to resolve issue with DataSet and Database connection in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, dataset, bindingsource

I am using VB.NET with an MS Access database. There are two tables with a relationship with each other.

I followed the following to make a database connection with the dataset and binding Source.

1. Under **Data Source** add new **Data Source**
2. **Database** as a data source type
3. **Dataset** as a database model >>
4. Chosen Data connection
5. Under the **database object**, I selected Table (s) which want for the purpose like customer table also clicked on views
6. Then finish.
7. Now at **Data source**, selected **Dataset** then Table of **Customers** and drag details and data grid view to the form and add buttons for adding, deleting updating the records.
8. Now run the application.

After running the application, But it's not **viewing**, **adding**, **updating**, and **deleting** records from/to the database.

Code for adding a record to the database

```
CustomersBindingSource.AddNew()
```

Code for updating a record to the database

```
CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
CustomersTableAdapter.Update(SrsbdbDataSet.Customers)
```

Code for deleting a record from the database

```
CustomersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
```

I also edited a connection string from the app.config file to check the connection string issue but not useful for the issue.

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can add some pictures to describe what you have done, so that it will help others make a test based on your test steps.

Comment: @XingyuZhao,  I uploaded video please [have a look](https://youtu.be/fOMEDIKAAOI)

Answer (score 1):

> CustomersBindingSource.AddNew()

This doesn't add a record *to the access database*, it adds a record to the BindingSource's list, which (when EndEdit is called on the BindingSource) is pushed into the `YourDataSetName.Customers` DataTable as a new DataRow - if you were to look at all the rows in `YourDataSetName.Customers` you'd see that there are some (downloaded from the db probably, when you started the app) and they have a [DataRowState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowstate?view=netcore-3.1) of Unchanged, and then there is the new one you added, with a DataRowState of Added

Nothing has been saved to the DB yet. This data is *only* in the dataset's datatable, which is a *client side representation* of a database table. It is *not* a database table in and of itself. It can certainly have more or fewer columns and of different types, than the database table. It's just temporary storage for database data; you download some, add some, change some, delete some, maybe save it etc. The relevant DataRow tracks all these things you do to its data and notes whether it is Added/Modified/Deleted/Unchanged etc

The TableAdapter is the thing that pushes the data back and forth between the DataTable and the database

You call `CustomersTableAdapter.Update()` when you want to save the data to the DB. Naming it `Update` was a crap idea on Microsoft's behalf, because it leads people to think it only performs SQL UPDATE queries; if it had been called `SaveChanges` (and later it was; EF uses SaveChanges) it would be more clear.. You just have to remember that one - "Update means Save"

So you call `Update(datatable or dataset here)` and pass in your DataTable with all its modified/deleted/added rows. The TableAdapter scans the whole DataTable row by row looking at the DataRowState of each row. If it's Added, then the TableAdapter will call its built in INSERT SQL query to save the row. If it's Modified, SQL UPDATE is performed. Deleted state causes an SQL DELETE. A datarow knows the original data that was downloaded and the data as it is now; this is sometimes vital in working out if someone else saved this row in the time we had it, so we can avoid overwriting their changes with ours

At the end of this process, the data has been saved, the rowstates have all been set from whatever they were, to Unchanged (because the data in the db is now the same, the row data no longer needs saving).

Think of that part of the process as being like the little * that appears on a text editor tab, when you edit the file - a datarow in state Added/Modified/Deleted has unsaved changes that need to be saved. After saving, the state goes back to Unchanged. Did I mention that TableAdapter.Update should have been called Save?

---

All in, the process for saving would be to ask the editing control to `EndEdit()` then ask the relevant bindingsource to `EndEdit` - this ensures we have a datatable with all changes committed and ready to save, and then call the `tableadapter.Update`. *Probably* the control the user was typing in will commit its edits when it loses focus, as the user clicks the save button.. But calling endedit makes sure. If you're uncertain, create a new form, drop a DataGridView on it out of the Data Sources window and take a look how the Save button is wired up - from memory it does a Validate, couple of EndEdits and a UpdateAll (TableAdapterManager, manages TableAdapters, calls Update on them in the right order to make sure that parent rows save before child rows)

---

If you started making more modifications, the row states would change again but just as before, the thing that commits the changes to the DB is TableAdapter.Update() regardless what kind of change you made

---

The final thing to watch out for here is that Access is a file based database. Probably you have your project in e.g.:

```
C:\projects\accesswhatever\
```

And you had your access db on e.g. your desktop:

```
c:\users\you\desktop\access.mdb
```

When you connected the access db into things, VS presented a long and wordy dialog (that no-one reads ;) ) where it basically says *"i'll put the db in your project, and I'll make it copy out to the bin folder when you build"*.

So you click OK without considering the ramifications of it and you build. Your disk now looks like:

```
 C:\users\you\desktop\access.mdb                            'call it DB X
 C:\projects\accesswhatever\access.mdb                      'call it DB Y
 C:\projects\accesswhatever\bin\debug\access.mdb            'call it DB Z
```

Your running program will save data in the last one, DB Z. Every time you build (which might happen every time you click play, if you make code changes), visual studio will delete Z and copy Y to Z.

You're now really confused; your code says it's saving. You're looking in either DB X on your desktop, or DB Y in your project base, and wondering where the heck is this data?

It's in DB Z, in the `bin\debug` folder, next to your app.exe - just remember that every time you build, VS wipes your changed database and replaces it with a clean one from way back when. If you want to change this, click the DB in solution explorer and set "Copy To Output" from "Copy Always" to "Copy If Newer". Now it'll only copy whenever you make a schema change, so.. Add a new table and then VS will wipe your nicely curated test db with a new one.. But it's more like OK because the new empty DB at least has that extra table that your program will crash without :)

Comment: Hi, I uploaded video please [have a look](https://youtu.be/fOMEDIKAAOI)

Comment: BindingSource.AddNew **does not add a record to a database**. BindingSource.EndEdit **does not edit anything in a database**. BindingSource.RemoveCurrent **does not remove a record from a database**. TableAdapter.Update **is not just for updating data**

Comment: (I watched that video... And you don't appear to have implemented anything I mentioned; you did at one point click your Update button, which would have saved the new -1 and -2 rows but then you were looking in the wrong database anyway. At the start of the video you deleted the most useful thing - the BindingNavigator, which had an Add Button, a Delete Button and a Save Button)

Comment: In your view please let me know what code to add a record, update a record and delete a record? If you think I'm doing wrong.. Many videos I saw over youtube where the above codes are working perfectly. I don't need a binding navigator at all. I have also tried with navigator but the same thing. I have also check database copy in the **debug** folder. nothing is also there.

Comment: I am really very angry about this issue. I tried all things but not useful. Sometimes data is coming in the database but it is too late. it's coming in debug folder. when I reopen the app then no data in datagridview as we added many records already. there is something seriously wrong from Microsoft end.

Comment: No, nothing's wrong with Microsoft - you just did that bit that I said you did, when I wrote in my answer *When you connected the access db into things, VS presented a long and wordy dialog (that no-one reads ;) ) where it basically says...* - Honestly, if you wrote a batch file script that copied a word document from your desktop to C:\temp, then you edited the one in C:\temp for 10 hours to have loads of good stuff in it, then you ran the batch script again and overwrote all your work, you *wouldn't* complain it was MS's fault.. You'd call yourself dumb for overwriting your own work.

Comment: That is all that is happening here; every time you build, VS copies a boatload of files to the output folder. The DB is one of them. It overwrites any earlier DB where your app has saved its data. If VS *didn't* overwrite stuff in the debug folder you'd be pretty hacked off cos non of your code changes would apply; your old bug-ridden EXE wouldn't be replaced with your new shiny, bug-free EXE and the app would stay at v0.1 forever.. Thing that ticks me off is that I've even told you how to solve it too. All you have to do is just... read what I've written

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to add the new record directly in DataGridView and use new OleDbDataAdapter for the connection.

Remove 'CustomersBindingSource.AddNew()', and edit record in DataGridView:

[image]

Code in 'Update Record' button.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim connstring = "your connection string"
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Customer", connstring)
    Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
    builder.QuotePrefix = "["
    builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
    adapter.Update(CustomerDataSet.Customer)

End Sub
```